Computing $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/2} \log x}{x^2 + 1}dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/2}}{x^2 + 1}dx$
I am trying to compute $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/2} \log x}{x^2 + 1}dx$$ and $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/2}}{x^2 + 1}dx$$ via the computation of $$\displaystyle\oint_C \frac{z^{1/2}\log z}{z^2 + 1}dz$$ where $C$ is the keyhole contour with branch cut along the positive real axis. The poles of the function are at $\pm i$ and so by the Residue Theorem I found $$\displaystyle\oint_C \frac{z^{1/2}\log z}{z^2 + 1}dz = \frac{\pi^2}{\sqrt{2}}$$.The integrals on $C_R, C_{\varepsilon}$ vanish as $R\to\infty, \varepsilon\to 0$. Writing $L_1$ for the line portion above the real axis, I found $$\displaystyle\int_{L_1} \frac{z^{1/2}\log z}{z^2 + 1}dz = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/2}\log x}{x^2 + 1}dx$$ and somewhat similarly for $L_2$, the line portion below the real axis, $$\displaystyle\int_{L_2} \frac{z^{1/2}\log z}{z^2 + 1}dz = -\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/2}\log x}{x^2 + 1}dx - 2\pi i \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/2}}{x^2 + 1}dx$$. However, combining all information together implies $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/2} \log x}{x^2 + 1}dx = \frac{\pi^2}{2\sqrt2}$$ and $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/2}}{x^2 + 1}dx=0$$. The first of these answers is correct, however I should have found $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1/2}}{x^2 + 1}dx = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$$ and am unsure as to where I've gone wrong in my calculations. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I understand that you want to master the residue calculus, but a quick method for the integrals is $u=x^2$, the use of the formulas $\int_0^{\infty}u^{a-1}dx/(1+u)^{a+b}=B(a,b),$ $B(p,1-p)=\pi/\sin \pi p,$ and $$ \int_0^{\infty}  u^{a-1}\log u, du/(1+u)$$$$=\frac{d}{ds}  \int_0^{\infty}  u^{a+s-1}, du/(1+u)]_{s=0}$$

Two issues:

The residue sum is not a real number. Your choice in branch puts $\arg z\in(0,2\pi)$, and as such $\arg i=\dfrac\pi2$ and $\arg(-i)=\dfrac{3\pi}2$.
$$\underset{z=i}{\operatorname{Res}} \frac{z^{1/2} \log z}{z^2+1} = \lim_{z\to i} \frac{|z|^{1/2} e^{\tfrac i2 \arg z} (\log |z| + i \arg z)}{z+i} = \frac{e^{i\tfrac\pi4} \cdot i \frac\pi2}{2i} = \frac{1+i}{4\sqrt2}\pi$$
$$\underset{z=-i}{\operatorname{Res}} \frac{z^{1/2} \log z}{z^2+1} = \lim_{z\to -i} \frac{|z|^{1/2} e^{\tfrac i2 \arg z} (\log |z| + i \arg z)}{z-i} = \frac{e^{i\tfrac{3\pi}4} \cdot i \frac{3\pi}2}{-2i} = \frac{3(1-i)}{4\sqrt2}\pi$$
Adding and multiplying by $i2\pi$ nets you $\dfrac{1+2i}{\sqrt2}\pi^2$.

The sign on the contribution of $L_2$ is incorrect. Bear in mind that $\arg z\to2\pi$ for both $z^{1/2}$ and $\log z$, so that
$$\int_{L_2}f(z)\,dz = \int_R^\varepsilon f(x-i\varepsilon) \, dx \to -\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/2} \color{red}{e^{\tfrac i2 \cdot 2\pi}} (\log x + i2\pi)}{x^2+1} \, dx \\
= \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/2} \log x}{x^2+1} \, dx + i2\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/2}}{x^2+1} \, dx$$



For the record,
\begin{align}J&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}\ln x}{1+x^2}dx\\
&\overset{u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}=-4\underbrace{\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln u}{1+u^4}du}_{=K}\\
A&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(xy)}{(1+x^4)(1+y^4)}dxdy\\
&\overset{u(x)=xy}=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{y^3\ln u}{(1+y^4)(u^4+y^4)}dudy\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^\infty\left[\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1+y^4}{u^4+y^4}\right)}{u^4-1}\right]_{y=0}^{y=\infty}\ln udu=\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2 u}{u^4-1}du}_{v=\frac{1}{u}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{(1-x^2)\ln^2 u}{u^4-1}du\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2 u}{u^2+1}du=-\frac{\pi^3}{16}
\end{align}
On the other hand,
\begin{align}A&=2K\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^4}dx\\
\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^4}dx&\overset{u=\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{2+\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2}dx\\
&\overset{u=x-\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2+u^2}du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}A&=\frac{K\pi}{\sqrt{2}}=-\frac{\pi^3}{16}\\
K&=-\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt{2}}\\
J&=-4K=\boxed{\frac{\pi^2}{2\sqrt{2}}}
\end{align}

Noting that
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x} \ln x}{1+x^2} d x=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial a} I(a)\right|_{a=\frac{1}{2}}
$$
where $I(a) =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan ^a \theta d \theta $.
Letting $x=\tan \theta$ transforms the integral into a Beta function.
\begin{aligned}
I(a)&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^a \theta \cos ^{-a} \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{2} B\left(\frac{a+1}{2}, \frac{1-a}{2}\right) \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2} \csc \left(\frac{\pi(a+1)}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
using   the reflection property of Beta function.
Differentiating w.r.t. $a$ gives
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} I(a)=-\frac{\pi^2}{4} \csc \frac{\pi(a+1)}{2} \cot \frac{\pi(a+1)}{2}
$$
Hence $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x} \ln x}{1+x^2} d x=\frac {\pi^2}{2\sqrt 2}$$
